# Spotify API no token provided

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, spotify, guzzle

How does Spotify API authorization work? I've read Spotify and Guzzle docs, put one and one together:

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', [
        'Authorization' =>  ['Bearer ' . $session_owner->spotify_token],
    ]);

    echo $res->getStatusCode(); // 200
    echo $res->getBody();
```

but the get this error message:

> "error": {
>       "status": 401,
>       "message": "No token provided" }

Comment: would be nice if downvoter left some feedback - why he did it

Comment: What is the value of `$session_owner->spotify_token`?  Do you use an IDE, set breakpoints & look at variable values? So much better than debug by `echo()`

Comment: @Mawg AQCzKqeQP1fKdnjnjAoRb1VWxmFn5bqumiFclUSNd1r-MSjWyd-uHiQCYJ7j7M4rXuiy0Ijh8bpeuPaSSEY4WUhiL04DLo4GuuBbI7qGc_Fejc4wllU3HQleOg_ZcxzlTuPrdQH2R4YUb74fj3U-Nk9GCdAJwjCQgu6kVWXnFbPLRlAL01h400NnjwnMJPA5zdzAnB_ZRANWeHcJFvCvTL7Ne3nG7d8DE86u (some characters have been changed)

Comment: Plus one for changing some chars :-)  I will try to understand https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/ and see if I can spot what you are doing wrong. It is bound to be something simple

Comment: Are you sure that the API uses `GET`, and not `POST`?

Comment: same result with `POST`

Comment: Keep using POST, and you should also pass the Authorization header as a string instead of an array, like so: `'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $session_owner->spotify_token,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $res = $client->post('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' =>  ['Bearer ' . $session_owner->spotify_token],
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Did that work? If so, you can accept your own answer in two days, which will help others 8n future

Comment: @Mawg Yeah, it did. Later it turned out that the code I received from the callback wasn't really a token, but a code i had to use to receive token. Now it's all good

Comment: Plus one for helping others; don't forget to accept you answer